# Please revise the google app script to make it concise and clear "Rows out of range" error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w-xKO4dAK4Z2EyOZ9bWa75qNm_EDiqEIAx786DD6NnY/edit?usp=sharing). It has three subsheets. CONFIDENTIAL : MIS, CONFIDENTIAL : MSA and Collection Sheet. I need a menu button which should read all data after 4th row of the both spreadsheets. And paste in the "Collection Sheet" as a single list, together with current date in E5 to last filled column. The following code does it well but I thing it is not a smart way to do it. And sometimes if the rows are in short in number, it gives "Rows out of range" msg, Would anyone expert give / suggest me some advice to improve it?

The code is given below.

```
function create_submit_sheet(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var target_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('Collection Sheet'))
  target_sheet.getRange('C1').setValue('');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("CONFIDENTIAL : MIS");
  var Avals = source_sheet.getRange("B4:B").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
  //Logger.log(Alast);
  var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Collection Sheet");
  //var roww = target_sheet.getDataRange.length;
  //var Avals = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  //var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
  //Logger.log(Alast);
  var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("B4:F"+Alast+4);
  //var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A6:H");
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
  //target_sheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);
  var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A"+(last_row+1)+":C"+(last_row+1));
  source_range.copyTo(target_range,{contentsOnly: true});



  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("CONFIDENTIAL : MSA");
  var Avals = source_sheet.getRange("B5:B").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
  var Alast1 = Alast;
  //Logger.log(Alast);
  var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Collection Sheet");
  //var roww = target_sheet.getDataRange.length;
  //var Avals = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  //var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
  //Logger.log(Alast);
  var source_range = source_sheet.getRange("B5:F"+Alast+5);
  //var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A6:H");
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
  //target_sheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);
  var target_range = target_sheet.getRange("A"+(last_row+1)+":C"+(last_row+1));
  source_range.copyTo(target_range,{contentsOnly: true});

  //SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F2').setValue('Hello');
  target_sheet.getRange('F4').setValue('প্রদত্ত');
  target_sheet.getRange('G4').setValue('তারিখ');
  var curDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+6", "MM/dd/yyyy")
  Avals = target_sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
  target_sheet.getRange(5,7, Alast-4 ).setValue(curDate);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('Collection Sheet'))


}
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). The link you shared does not point to a sample spreadsheet. See [How to share a Google Sheets demo spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [appendRows_()](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/159426/269219) utility function. You can use it like this:

```
function appendToSubmitSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Collection Sheet');
  const values =
    ss.getRange('CONFIDENTIAL : MIS!B4:F').getValues()
      .concat(ss.getRange('CONFIDENTIAL : MSA!B4:F').getValues())
      .filter(row => row.join(''));
  appendRows_(targetSheet, values, 2);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting "ReferenceError: appendRows_ is not defined
appendToSubmitSheet" is it possinle to fix?

Comment: I am really not an expert in Google apps script. Would you please do it for me?

Comment: I have tried a lot ... but failed to do that. Please show me the path.

Comment: I do not see the relation. I need nothing regarding HTML.

Comment: The link you posted in the first line of your question does not point to a sample spreadsheet. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _manually entered_ desired results there. It is unclear why you are referring to HTML.

Comment: SORRY everybody! Correct spreadsheet shared now.

Comment: It looks like you have correctly inserted the `appendToSubmitSheet()` function in the script project. Now insert the `appendRows_ ()` and `getLastRow_()` functions the same way. They are available [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/159426/269219). Then run `appendToSubmitSheet()` instead of `create_submit_sheet()`.

Comment: Too complex to me !

Comment: Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script are listed at [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).